# Running process as administrator in cross domain environment using c#

Tags: c#, impersonation

Please help,

I have posted before how to do impersonation of administrator on remote machine. After a lot of try and errors It works on some level but the problem is there is no clear specification up there on how impersonation works and I was not able to do as much as I want it to work.

When I use

LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS and LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT

My problem used to be ERROR 136 which is Invalid Username and Password but I figured out that.

Another problem now ERROR 138 when I use

LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE and LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50

What I really want is I want to install my service on the remote machines with out UAC in my way.

What I have

- I have the domain administrator account and password
- I have machines which are not in the domain

Please help me to give me a way to install my service in a cross domain environment.

Comment: sorry but you need admin privileges if you want to not have UAC in your way.

Comment: Are you talking about for the machines that are not in the domain? That I am required to have admin privilege? Because I was assuming for the machines in the domain I have Administrator Domain account so the impersonation has to work.

Comment: for both. I think that UAC works on machine/OS instance level. Therefore you need local trust/admin access with the user account, and it must be given locally. If the domain admin account was propagated as the admin to each machine, then that will work for those, but not for the others. However, if that account is simply labelled as the domain admin account and not propagated to the machines, it won't work anywhere.